# Create new column based on condition of another column if value falls in a range

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have df such as:

```
Hour 
12:00pm
12:00am
3:00pm
2:00pm
11:00pm
Continued....
```

I want to create a new column that gives the segment for that time based on condtions such as
if between 6:00am and 11:59am then Default, if between 12:00pm and 3:59pm then timely, if between 4:00pm and 11:59pm then late and if between 12:00am and 5:59am then nonvalid.

Want to use something like below code:

```
def func(row):
    if row['Hour'] >= 06:00am & < 12:00pm:
        return 'defualt'
    elif row['Hour'] >= 12:00pm & < 04:00pm:
        return 'timley' 
    elif row['Hour'] >= 04:00pm & < 12:00am:
        return 'late' 
    elif row['Hour'] >= 12:00am & < 06:00am:
        return 'nonvalid' 
    else:
        return 'other'

df['Segment'] = df.apply(func, axis=1)
```

But the hour column is not a datetime so not sure if it will read the ranges in my function.

```
Expected output:

     Hour   Segment
    12:00pm timley
    12:00am nonvalid
    3:00pm  timley
    2:00pm  timley
    11:00pm late
```

Comment: could you show expected output?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think here is necessary convert bins and also columns values and pass to [`cut`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html):

```
dates = pd.to_datetime(df['Hour'], format='%I:%M%p')
b = pd.to_datetime(['12:00am','06:00am','12:00pm','04:00pm', '11:59pm'], format='%I:%M%p')
l = ['nonvalid','Default', 'timely','late']
df['new'] = pd.cut(dates, bins=b, labels=l, right=False)
print (df)
      Hour       new
0  12:00pm    timely
1  12:00am  nonvalid
2   3:00pm    timely
3   2:00pm    timely
4  11:00pm      late
```

Test with more dates:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Hour': pd.date_range('2020-01-01', periods=24, freq='H')})
df['Hour'] = df['Hour'].dt.strftime('%I:%M%p')
#print (df)

dates = pd.to_datetime(df['Hour'], format='%I:%M%p')
b = pd.to_datetime(['12:00am','06:00am','12:00pm','04:00pm', '11:59pm'], format='%I:%M%p')
l = ['nonvalid','Default', 'timely','late']
df['new'] = pd.cut(dates, bins=b, labels=l, right=False)
print (df)
       Hour       new
0   12:00AM  nonvalid
1   01:00AM  nonvalid
2   02:00AM  nonvalid
3   03:00AM  nonvalid
4   04:00AM  nonvalid
5   05:00AM  nonvalid
6   06:00AM   Default
7   07:00AM   Default
8   08:00AM   Default
9   09:00AM   Default
10  10:00AM   Default
11  11:00AM   Default
12  12:00PM    timely
13  01:00PM    timely
14  02:00PM    timely
15  03:00PM    timely
16  04:00PM      late
17  05:00PM      late
18  06:00PM      late
19  07:00PM      late
20  08:00PM      late
21  09:00PM      late
22  10:00PM      late
23  11:00PM      late
```

Comment: When I run I get error of AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values, as Hour is not in datetime format @jezrael

Comment: @Chris90 Yop, in column are strings. And it is reason why is used `dates = pd.to_datetime(df['Hour'], format='%I:%M%p')` for convert strings to datetimes.